# How do I know what version of a Maven plugin to use?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How do I know what version of a Maven plugin to use?

For example, where on the horrible Maven website can I find a list of versions of the compiler plugin?
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you're looking for the issue tracker, which shows issues, versions, changelogs, etc. On just about any of the "horrible" Maven plugin pages, you'll find a link to the issue tracker on the left side under "Project Information".

Comment: Ah, there it is, thanks. This page in particular is excellent:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Achangelog-panel    It's a shame it's not more accessible from the Maven site itself.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do

1. Go to http://mvnrepository.com
2. Search for maven-compiler-plugin
3. You should find the first one is the one you need. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin
4. Find the one with the latest version and use that one

The above works because maven repo also has the latest plugins. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think a changelog is offered here. If the developers are nice, sometimes they put links to their changelog. For example the maven compiler has a changeset link. But again this is not guaranteed.